# Issues with ssrs datasets grouping using visual studio 2019

Tags: reporting-services

I have built several reports using ssrs through visual studio 2012. When importing it into visual studio 2019 and I open the dataset to work on it, it keeps changing back and forth between Hide and Show grouping. This makes it impossible to work on the dataset.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Change the visibility in the group properties to Hide or Show with an expression or just change it to always show.

Comment: That's the issue. It changes itself back and forth when I open the dataset. It goes to show then within a millisecond it switches to hide, then within another millisecond it changes back to show and just keeps this up.